# Build emacs from source error

Tags: emacs, build, makefile

I try to build emacs-23.1 from source.

First :

```
./configure
```

Then i try to

```
make
```

But get error at the start:

```
$ make
cd lib-src; make all                            \
      CC='gcc' CFLAGS='-g -O2 -Wno-pointer-sign ' CPPFLAGS='-D_BSD_SOURCE  ' \
      LDFLAGS='-Wl,-znocombreloc ' MAKE='make'
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/emacs-23.1/lib-src'
Makefile:144: *** commands commence before first target.  Stop.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/emacs-23.1/lib-src'
make: *** [lib-src] Error 2
```

How can i fix it? I try many emacs versions and every time i get this error.

Thank you.

Comment: http://theory.uwinnipeg.ca/localfiles/infofiles/make/make_121.html

Comment: Where are you downloading the source from? Are you following the instructions in the INSTALL file (and the INSTALL.bzr file if you're using a checkout)?

Comment: Exact same issue. Did you ever fix this? @jeremiahd - this happens with the clean default Ubuntu install in a virtualbox. The INSTALL file merely recommends running .\configure and then running make

Comment: db48x is almost certainly correct in their answer / aartist in their comment. Either grab a different source tarball, a Makefile from a different minor version (and hope it works), or open the file in a Makefile-aware editor and edit it. It's probably a whitespace error, and although it's pretty weird for it to be one that got distributed, it's not ridiculously so.

Answer (score 1):

That makefile is incorrect; it probably has a stray tab character in it. As configure generates that makefile, perhaps the makefile.in is incorrect, or perhaps some variable that configure substitutes into it has a tab in it. I suspect the latter as you state that the problem occurs when compiling multiple versions of emacs.

Answer (score 1):

It might because "./configure" cannot generate "src/Makefile" properly from "src/Makefile.in".
It cannot understand "\" at the end of line properly. So I change the "\^J" -> " ", i.e. remove the "\" at the end of line and join the two lines. Both "src/Makefile.in" and "lib-src/Makefile.in". I am not sure the root of cause, anyway, I can build "emacs"